# How to I load Salesforce1 onto an Android mobile device that does not have the Play Store?

Tags: salesforce1-app, android

We are testing an app on a barcode scanning Android-based device that doesn't have the Google Play Store.  Any suggestions on how I can install Salesforce1?

Comment: Please google and find the APK and install it by opening it in Salesforce. This is a generic way of downloading apps without goolge playstore

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, If you want to sideload Salesforce1 you could download the APK through a site like [Evozi](http://apps.evozi.com) (that'll give you a download link like this http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/?id=com.salesforce.chatter), then install it using [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) (the Android Developer Bridge). If you're wanting to uninstall/re-install often then this is a nice quick approach.